# Why the function using socket to transfer data makes my activity crash?

Tags: android, sockets

I am now using a function to transfer data to the server. The function uses socket to transfer data. However, when I use this function in my activity, it makes this activity crash and jumps to the prior activity. I wonder why this happened?

```
public void transferdata(float[] a){
    Socket socket;
    try{
        socket=new Socket("192.168.86.2",1989);
        OutputStream outputstream=socket.getOutputStream();
        byte[] b=floatToByte(a);
        outputstream.write(b,0,0);
        outputstream.flush();

    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    private void touchEventHandler(float touchpoint_X, float touchpoint_Y){
    float []a=new float[2];
    transferdata(a);

    }
```

Comment: Crashes leave traces, you need to find the relevant one and add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you catch a general Exception and see its message, you will see it is NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Network operation must be done in Java concurrent or Kotlin coroutine, in old versions you can use AsyncTask.